# Count unique number of elements based on another cell range

Tags: excel, excel-2007, worksheet-function, countif, array-formulas

I have two columns in my Excel sheet. Column A contains `Wk No`,  Column B  `Dates`:

```
Wk. No    Dates  
1228      9-Jul  
1228      10-Jul  
1228      11-Jul  
1228      11-Jul  
1228      12-Jul  
1228      13-Jul  
1229      16-Jul  
1229      16-Jul  
1229      17-Jul
```

I want the following result:

```
Wk. No    No-of-days  
1228       5  
1229       2
```

How to get this in Excel? I can get the number of unique days but cannot control the formula to calculate unique days based on the week number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
COUNTIF(RANGE,CRITERIA)
```

Like

```
Wk.No          No-of-days
1228           =COUNTIF(RANGE,<Cell Reference of 1228>)
1229           =COUNTIF(RANGE,<Cell Reference of 1229>)
```

Comment: Countif gives the overall number of count matching the week number. 6 for 1228 and 3 for 1229 will be result. I need the unique days in that week number (no duplicates)

Answer (score 0):

If `Wk. No` is in A1 and `1228` and `1229` in C2 and C3, respectively, then:

```
=SUM(IF(A2:A10=C2,1/(COUNTIFS(A2:A10,C2,B2:B10,B2:B10)),0))
```

entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and copied down one row should suit. Courtesy of [Get Digital Help](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2011/07/12/count-unique-distinct-values-that-meet-multiple-criteria-in-excel/) where a full explanation is available.

Of course would be much easier with Excel 2013.